# Blank display after waking up, using external monitor as primary on a HP laptop

Tags: xfce, debian, display-manager

I'm running

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

with XFCE. My computer specification is :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H KT Redirection (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev 31)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
```

I have also following ports of which I use the DP-1 to my external monitor

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.01 +  59.97    59.96    59.93    40.01  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Dp-1 is set as my primary display. Every time I want to put my computer to suspend, go for rest and come back, and press a key to wake the computer I see only a black screen. This is the sleep log I've got so far:

```
Sep 08 00:18:59 maroufi systemd-sleep[2784]: Suspending system...
Sep 08 12:52:13 maroufi systemd-sleep[2784]: System resumed.
Sep 08 13:10:12 maroufi systemd-sleep[5738]: Suspending system...
Sep 08 18:56:31 maroufi systemd-sleep[5738]: System resumed.
Sep 08 19:34:44 maroufi systemd-sleep[12201]: Suspending system...
Sep 09 17:23:50 maroufi systemd-sleep[12201]: System resumed.
Sep 09 17:37:38 maroufi systemd-sleep[14461]: Suspending system...
Sep 09 19:17:33 maroufi systemd-sleep[14461]: System resumed.
```

So what I did so far to solve this problem is:

1. Go to tty1 and type sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service
   This is not good at all since it closes down all my opened applications
2. I installed arandr and make a script as following (with the hastag sign and !/bin/bash at the beginning):

   `xrandr --output eDP-1 --off --output HDMI-3 --off --output HDMI-2 --off --output HDMI-1 --off --output DP-3 --off --output DP-2 --off --output DP-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal`

I saved this script and make a key binding ctrl+Win+P. This did not work at all.

3. I went to tty1 again and run that script from there. The output I saw was " `Can't not open display` "

This problem is really annoying and I really want to get rid of this once for all.

Comment: If the monitor is the default display, then that might be causing the problem. Switch the default display to the laptop and tell me if it changes anything.

Comment: @TheMATEMan tried it. Still same thing.

Comment: Perhaps go to tty1 when you boot and log in there, run `sudo systemctl stop lightdm.service`. Then you could run `startx` to see if the same issue occurs without lightdm. You may need to install the `xinit` package to be able to run `startx`.